# Custom error handling with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

The REST Api I'm working with has custom codes and messages which are sent from server depending on the state, I would like to implement a custom `Callback<T>` that calls the `success` method only if the status code was 0.

**Example SUCCESS Response received from server:**

```
{
  "code":"0",
  "message":"success",
  "data": {
    "actual_data":"goes_here",
    "need_to_construct_objects","from_data"
  }
}
```

**Example of FAILURE Response:**

```
{
  "code":"301",
  "message":"wrong_password",
  "data": {
    "actual_data":"will_be_null",
    "no_need_to_construct_objects","from_data"
  }
}
```

`code` and `message` are returned by all requests, the `data` contains the actual response values, so I would like to do the following:

1. Check the **code** and **message** and only call `success()` if code is 0.
2. Call `failure()` if request failed or **code != 0**
3. Construct custom objects based on the **data** response and pass them via `success()`

What is the best way to do this? I searched everywhere and could not find a good solution. The only one I got was to let all custom objects have the `code` and `message` fields too and check their values inside `success()`, but this could cause problems in future in case someone forgets to check the `code` before proceeding.

Comment: Actually Retrofit provides way to build your own custom error handler!

Comment: Could you give me some pointers or where to look at for a sample?

Comment: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

"CUSTOM ERROR HANDLING"

Comment: That is for status codes, what I'm looking for is inside the response, so Http 200 is returned but inside the response data there is the errors/messages or none.

Comment: It gets the whole response and handles it accordingly! If your response contains more data you can use it in your own way! It's not only for the status code!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are wrong, it won't even be called because if result is Http 200 retrofit will call `success()` and therefore there's no RetrofitError object nor `failure()` calls.

Comment: If that's the case then sorry for confusing you!

Comment: Has you find a good way to do this? I am also has same problem with you

Comment: I do have the same problem?? Did you find anything??

Answer (score 3):

You can do that quickly by just making an abstract class that implements Callback, and declare your own abstract success and failure methods. The abstract class will handle Retrofit's standard callback methods, interpret the response and call the abstract methods accordingly.

I think another possible approach to this is to override Retrofit's Client interface to build your own Response object.

If you extend [OkClient](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/b7e9f27ba451ede764f3fe51528c4ff192f2a79a/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/client/OkClient.java), it can go like this:

```
public class CustomClient extends OkClient {

    @Override public Response execute(Request request) throws IOException {
          Response originalRespone = super.execute(request);

          int statusCode = 0;
          //TODO: read JSON response here (using GSON or similar, and extract status code and message... etc.)

          //Convert the status code to HTTP standard status codes, according to the documentation you have.
          if(statusCode == 0) statusCode = 200;
          //Reconstruct a Response object
          return new Response(originalResponse.getUrl(), statusCode, originalResponse.getReason() /*should probably replace with parsed message*/, originalResponse.getHeaders(), originalResponse.getBody());
    }
```

This may be more work than handling your case in Callback, but I think it can help if at some point the API transitions to RESTful API conventions.

This solution comes with its own problem though, because that means the JSON conversion will run twice. One in your client, and another one by Retrofit. Not sure the correct way to do that at the moment. Probably something around TypedInput and a dummy Converter that passes already converted objects.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom ResponseBodyConverter like this:

```
public class CustomResponseBodyConverter<T> implements Converter<ResponseBody, T> {
private final TypeAdapter<T> adapter;

CustomResponseBodyConverter(TypeAdapter<T> adapter) {
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException,CustomException {
    String json = "";
    try {
        String body = value.string();
        json = new JSONObject(body).getJSONObject("data").toString();
        int code = new JSONObject(body).getInt("code");
        String message = new JSONObject(body).getString("message");
        if(code != 0){
            throw new CustomException(message);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return adapter.fromJson(json);
   }
}
```

Comment: How do this use with Retrofit

Answer (score 1):

It's a better idea to implement a custom callback. You can an example about it below.

```
public abstract class DefaultRequestCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    public abstract void failure(Meta meta);

    public abstract void success(T responseBean);

    @Override
    public void success(T baseResponseBean, Response response) {
        // You can check your responsebean's error code and 
        // convert it to a default error
        BaseResponseBean bean = (BaseResponseBean) baseResponseBean;
        if (bean == null) {
            failure(new Meta(ApplicationConstants.ERROR_RETROFIT, "Unknown Error!"));
        } else if (bean.getMeta() != null && bean.getMeta().getCode() != ApplicationConstants.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            failure(bean.getMeta());
        } else {
            success(baseResponseBean);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        // Convert default error to your custom error.
        Meta meta = new Meta(ApplicationConstants.ERROR_RETROFIT, "Error Unknwon");
        failure(meta);
    }
}
```

Give your custom callback to your retrofit service interface method.

```
void yourMethod(DefaultRequestCallback<YourResponseBean> callback);
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This will at least get you started. You can basically create your own custom callback and then handle the success. Look at what was sent and do what you need to.

```
  public class CustomCallback implements Callback {
    @Override
        public void success(Object o, Response response) {

                //Check for success
                //if( Success )
                //callback.success(o, response);
                //else
                //Check for error
                //callback.failure(error);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can have a class that maps your json response:

```
class CustomResponse {
  String code;
  String message;
  Data data;

  static class Data {
    String actualData;
    String needToContructObjects;
    String noNeedToContructObjects;
  }
}
```

Then, since you're back to the java objects world, you can have a factory-like object inside your success method callback that creates the desired object based on the returned custom response. If you want to get this response in the failure callback, I'd reconsider using Retrofit, since your API is not following a good Rest design.

Although this is plenty possible, and understanding you might not be involved on the API development, be aware this is not a good API design approach. If you are POSTing a login request to the server, you can understand this request as a request to create a resource (an authenticated user session, for instance). If you don't send the correct parameters (the correct username and password in this specific case), the server should reject the resource creation request and send back a 4-hundred-something (4xx) http status code indicating your request was not correct somehow. Retrofit would understand this 4xx status code and call your failure callback, where you could handle the response appropriately.